Where does Bhagavad Gita talk about levels of reality?
According to Advaita Vedanta there are three levels of reality:
1: Paramarthika Satya: Absolute Reality, Brahman.
2: Vyahavarika Satya: Empirical Reality, our world as Mithya.
3: Pratibhasika Satya: Our dream world.
Where does the Bhagavad Gita talk about the above levels of reality?

Bhagavad Gita does not talk about 3 levels of reality, but it talks about 2 levels of Reality (Real and Unreal), right in the second chapter at the beginning of Bhagavan's instruction to Arjuna.
Bhagavan Krishna differentiates between the transient world and permanent Atman. He calls the transient phenomenon as unreal and implies that the permanent Atman is real.

2.14 But the contacts of the organs with the objects are the producers of cold and heat, happiness and sorrow. They have a beginning and an end, (and) are transient. Bear them, O descendant of Bharata.


2.15 O (Arjuna, who are) foremost among men, verily, the person whom these do not torment, the wise man to whom sorrow and happhiness are the same he is fit for Immortality.

Why must Arjuna bear these transient phenomena like happiness/sorrow and cold/heat? Because, as the Lord mentions in the next sloka, these are unreal, being transient.

2.16 Of the unreal there is no being; the real has no non-existence. But the nature of both these, indeed, has been realized by the seers of Truth.

What then is Real, mentioned in the above sloka? This is answered in next sloka.

2.17 But know That to be indestructible by which all this is pervaded. None can bring about the destruction of this Immutable.

The indestructible/permanent Atman is Real.
Thus, there are 2 levels of Reality - unreal (transient) and real (permanent).

So what is the basis of the advaitin viewpoint?

@VedantSingh This is same as advaitic viewpoint. Vyavaharika+pratibhasika satya are unreal. Paramarthika satya is real.
